# Is there a way to quit Node.js and launch VIM on a file?

Tags: node.js, vim, terminal

I'm creating a simple terminal-based file manager on Node.js. Is there any way I can, from while my program is running on the terminal, quit it and open a file with VIM?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply:

```
require('child_process').spawn('vim', ['test.txt'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
```

If there is nothing left in the Node.js event loop when vim exits, then node will exit automatically as well. Or, if you need to guarantee node will exit when vim does:

```
var vim = require('child_process').spawn('vim', ['test.txt'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
vim.on('exit', process.exit);
```

As for closing the node application *before* vim exits, that's not really possible because vim inherits standard input/output/error streams from the spawning process (node) which are destroyed when node exits.

Comment: this is not working as expected... when I press any key it leaves VIM back to the node.js process...

Comment: Found the problem. I had to do `stdin.pause()` before spawning vim. Thanks!

Comment: How would one do this with sublime? I replaced vim with subl. It opens sublime, but exit gets called right away, not after the file has been saved, etc.